# cakephp 3 how to prevent more than one login with the same username / password at the same time?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Good Morning,
  I am using cakephp 3 for the first time, and I wonder how can I prevent that two or more people to log in with the same username at the same time?

I'm using auth component to login and logout and everything is working beautifully.

Researched and understood that need to use Sessions, then did the following as the Cookbook:
  in app.php:

```
'Session' => [
'defaults' => 'database'
]
```

and created the table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
`id` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`data` BLOB, -- or BYTEA for PostgreSQL
`expires` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

It saves the session in the database. But still allows the same username to connect to sistem more than once at the same time, for example i m testing on localhost, with two browsers logged in with the same username.

I'm posting the question because I do not like to reinvent the wheel, and I know cakephp is quite complete.
  So I wonder if there is any component ready, or what configuration should change for this to work?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then the database I created this field:

```
 id_logged varchar 15,
```

the login function looked like this:

```
 public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
                $idsessao = uniqid();

                $query = $this->Users->query();
                $query->update()
                    ->set(['id_logged' => $idsessao])
                    ->where(['id' => $user['id']])
                    ->execute();

            $user['id_logged'] = $idsessao;
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);

                return $this->redirect([
                    'controller' => 'x',
                    'action' => 'x'
                ]);

        } else{
            $this->Flash->error(__('x'));
        }

    }
}
```

and inside each controller I use this:

```
 public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    if ($this->request->action != 'index') {
        return true;
    }
    $usuario = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User');
    $idbanco = (new UsersController())->id_logged_db();

    if ($idbanco != $usuario['id_logged']){

        $this->Flash->error(__('x'));
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

The id_logged_db function is this:

```
public function id_logged_db(){

    $this->autoRender = false;
    $usuario = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User');

   $id = $this->Users->get($usuario['id'])->id_logged;

    return $id;
}
```

this way, every time the User access the index actions, the system tests the id save at login time.
It works perfectly as I needed.
  I am by posting the answer, so you can help someone with the same doubt.